# IE Error - 0.url is null or not an object in line 692

Tags: mediaelement.js

I can't get this working in IE at all, I've tried IE7 and IE8(+ compat mode).  I've searched the support, and see I'm the only person to have the problem.

This happens immediately when executing:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1');
```

So it's not even getting through the first line.  Tracing it through, it seems to be because no media files are loaded, but this is loading the media files?

I also tried a single line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("video,audio").mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);
```

});

still, same error.  works in all other browsers, but unfortunately I need to support IE7+

Any pointers on how to get this going?

Comment: Another thing I noticed, I can stop the error by adding a 'src' attribute to the mp4 in the video tag, but the IE version then displays 2 video windows, and all the other browsers stop working, as in it never reaches the 'success' function, so I'm assuming the lot is breaking.  I've had the same behaviour with 2.0.x(I think 7) and 2.1.1.  There's obviously something very simple I'm doing wrong as nobody else appears to be having problems like this

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Did you find a solution Stu?

Comment: Hi,

I have the same issue on IE8. My JS is above the <video> tags. I have the following error:

`0.url is null or not an object line 875 of mediaelement-and-player.js`

On line 875 I have:

`result.url = mediaFiles[0].url;`

I did a `console.log(mediaFiles);` which output an empty object in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that the script is before the audio or video tags??

Check this: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/140

I faced the same issue and fixed by moving the media element script avobe the video tag.